# React Native useContext Hooks Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I would like to encapsulate the logic for a function to send push notifications so that it can be called from anywhere in the app. The push notifications API requires a jwtToken to be passed in the header. I want to call useContext on the AuthContextProvider to extract the token but the rules of hooks don't allow my function to call useContext since it isn't a React function component.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "@context/AuthContextProvider";

export const sendPushNotification = async function (notificationObject) {
   const { authData } = useContext(AuthContext); //**<-- Fails with hooks error**
   const authToken = authData.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
   ...
```

Here is the code that calls the function:

```
function AddToDoScreen() {
   ...
   function handleSubmitAsync() {
      ...
      let pushNotificationObject = {
          profileIDs: [values.profileID],
          title: "Push Notification Title",
          body: "Push Notification Message",
        };

        sendPushNotification(pushNotificationObject);
```

I think this can be accomplished with a custom hook, but I'm not sure how. I tried starting the function name with use, but that didn't help.

Any pointers on how to implement this so I don't have to get the IdToken in each function that wants to call the sendPushNotification function?

BTW, I know you can't call Hooks inside nested functions. I tried moving the code up into the AddToDoScreen function but got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically two options here:

1. Create a custom hook that encapsulates all the logic and returns a callback function a component can invoke.

   ```
   import React, { useCallback, useContext } from "react";
   import { AuthContext } from "@context/AuthContextProvider";

   export const usePushNotification = () => {
     const { authData } = useContext(AuthContext);
     const authToken = authData.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;

     const sendPushNotification = useCallback(async (notificationObject) => {
       ... logic to use token and notification object and send push ...
     }, [authToken]);

     return {
       sendPushNotification
     };
   };
   ```

   ```
   function AddToDoScreen() {
     const { sendPushNotification } = usePushNotification();

     ...

     function handleSubmitAsync() {
       ...
       const notification = {
         profileIDs: [values.profileID],
         title: "Push Notification Title",
         body: "Push Notification Message",
       };

       sendPushNotification(notification);
     }

     ...
   }
   ```
2. Access the `authToken` value from the context in the React component and pass it to the callback function.

   ```
   export const sendPushNotification = async ({
     authToken,
     notification,
   }) => {
     ... logic to use token and notification object and send push ...
   };
   ```

   ```
   function AddToDoScreen() {
     const { authData } = useContext(AuthContext);
     const authToken = authData.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;

     ...

     function handleSubmitAsync() {
       ...
       const notification = {
         profileIDs: [values.profileID],
         title: "Push Notification Title",
         body: "Push Notification Message",
       };

       sendPushNotification({
         authToken,
         notification,
       });
     }

     ...

   }
   ```

Comment: Drew, thank you! I went with Option #1 and it works perfectly! The callback was what I needed.